# Lifehacker Syndication Photo Contest: Let's Go!

Tags: discussion, contest, crowdhacker

**No Lifehacker contests are currently running. See below for the latest winning submission and check back soon for the next opportunity to have your work published and help us out.**

- [“How to properly cook a steak?”](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2142/crowdhacker-contest-how-to-properly-cook-a-steak)

---

Maybe you've noticed [Crowdhacker](http://lifehacker.com/crowdhacker/), (y)our weekly column at Lifehacker. Hopefully you haven't noticed how crappy the title photos can be.

Let's change that. And let's do it in a way that gives you an opportunity to show off your photography skills to tens of thousands of readers.

**The Crowdhacker title photo contest starts now.**

Starting today, you will see meta posts featuring a soon-to-be-syndicated Stack Exchange Q&A denoted with the tag [[crowdhacker]](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crowdhacker). Each of these posts is a contest that functions very much like [Picture of the Week](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured-photo).

**Submission Rules:**

- Images must reflect the question posed, the answer(s) given, or the general content represented in that particular contest Q&A.
- Images must be 640 x 360.
- Limit one photo per person per contest.

**Voting Rules:**

- Up votes only. Down votes will not be counted towards a submission's final score.
- Vote for the image that you think looks sharp & best represents the spirit of the particular contest Q&A. Remember: these are title images, and the more professional they look, the more likely Lifehacker will choose to feature them. Reward high-quality submissions.

The submission with the most up votes at the end of the contest period will be featured at Lifehacker, attributed with a name and link of the winner's choosing.

***Fine print:*** In the event of a tie, Lifehacker will choose among winners. Stack Exchange and Lifehacker reserve the right to reject a photo for any reason. By submitting you are agreeing to license your photo under [CC-BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). This agreement does not apply to versions of the image not submitted.

Ready. Set. Snap.

Comment: What happen to the other two contests such as http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/crowdhacker-contest-how-to-find-out-whats-costing-you-all-that-money-on-your ?

Comment: We've decided to only run two concurrent contest at a time on PhotoSE: The PotW and Sam's LifeHacker contest. Four concurrent contests felt like too much for our community to absorb given our size and membership activity. We're not quite SO. ;)