# Crowdhacker Contest: "How to properly cook a steak?"

Tags: discussion, contest, crowdhacker

## [**Q&A: How to properly cook a steak?**](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/267/how-do-you-properly-cook-a-steak)

**Submission Rules:**

- Images must reflect the question posed, the answer(s) given, or the general content represented in the above Q&A.
- Images must be 640 x 360 px.
- Limit one submission per person per contest.

**Voting Rules:**

- Upvotes only. Downvotes will not be counted towards a submission's final score.
- Vote for the image that you think looks sharp & best represents the spirit of the Q&A at the top of this page. Remember: these are title images, and the more professional they look, the more likely [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/) will choose to feature them. Reward high-quality submissions.

The submission with the most upvotes at the end of the contest period will be made the title image for [Crowdhacker](http://lifehacker.com/crowdhacker/) - Stack Exchange's weekly column at Lifehacker. In the event of a tie, Lifehacker will choose among winners. The published photograph be attributed with the **name** and **link** of the winner's choosing.

Contest ends: **Fri, April 20 at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4)**

See [here](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/lifehacker-syndication-photo-contest-lets-go) for official rules.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Comment: Wow, that person looks like they are literally on fire!

Answer (score 0):

[image: steak with green sauce]

Comment: Your steak is a little green.

Comment: you're so funny

Comment: BTW, you didn't use the rule of thirds.

Comment: To me it looks like the focus of the image is the fork. In that respect, it *does* look a little green.

Comment: @J.Walker - 1. this isn't the place for critique 2. The "rule" of thirds isn't a rule, just a guideline.  Break it when it feels right.

Comment: I *know* that. It was a *joke*. Apparently one of our senses of humour is lacking.

Comment: If I _may_ seriously break the critique rule a tiny bit here, though, @dpollit, I'dsuggest cleaning up the mess on the table in the lower right corner and resubmitting.

Comment: Thank you for all of the great comments... I see coneslayer, the only person who did submit his own work, did not comment.

Comment: @rfusca - I disagree a bit here, I think some critique in a photo contest is a good thing. I feel that way about our weekly one too. What the heck, this site is what we make of it and good critique can help us learn. Mind you, I agree on the rule of thirds... :)

Comment: JoanneC: We get stuff like [this week](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1252/weekly-featured-image-jul-11-11) then, which is not a bright, shining moment in our history as a site.

Comment: @rfusca - Yes and no. That's an extreme example, to be fair, though I see your point. Nevertheless, critique is a valid path to growth as a photographer and, to be honest, I think we're going to have to consider some level of that if the site is to maintain a strong pulse.

Comment: JoanneC: I would love to see us get it *in some form*, I just haven't seen a form that would work for the site.

Comment: I think we should purposely and explicitly avoid critique in this kind of forum. A contest should just be a contest, not a contest and a critique of the contested works. If we ever decide to do critique, it should be explicit and in a form where we can maintain some modicum of control over the tone and direction critiques take so as not to outrageously offend our members (as that has indeed lead to loss of members in the past.)